# Google Maps Geocoder - Get values into callback

Tags: asynchronous, callback, geocoding, currying

I have some troubles with the Geocoder from Google Maps.

The main idea is, that I have a list with estates (flat, house, ...) in it and I want to search for Points of Interest (POIs; university, cafe, etc.) nearby the estates with some given range. There is no problem, it works fine.

BUT what I want to do now is, to "delete", or better said, make the markers invisible, which have no Points of Interest in the given range nearby.
In the code below you will see, that I have the geocode in a for loop, and for every estate which it gets it sets the POIs. Now I want to give over the estates which it uses at this time, checks if there are results nearby, if not it should set the marker of the estate on map to null. The problem is, that I can't give over the id of the estate, so I can set the marker to null with this specific ID.

Right now it works partially, but it always deletes the markers randomly. (Currently it is done with some counter to delete the index... but I want to delete it with the id).

**So, the main question is,** how can I hand over the current ID of the estate from the for loop into the callback and delete the marker with the same ID?

To understand the code i should say that "immo" or "immobilien" is the german word for estates.

Here's the code:

```
function geocodePoi(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    var poiCat = document.getElementById("poi").value;
    poiList.push(poiCat);
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var poi = document.getElementById('poi').value;
    var radius = document.getElementById('range').value;

    var poiArray = [];
    poiArray.push(poi);

    var latlng;

    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
            latlngDic = {lat: latlng.lat(), lng: latlng.lng()};
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            for (i = 0; i < immobilien.length; i++) {
                currentImmo = immobilien[i].id;
                currentImmoList.push(currentImmo);
                var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
                    service.nearbySearch({
                        location: new google.maps.LatLng(immobilien[i].longitude,
                                                         immobilien[i].latitude),
                        radius: radius,
                        types: poiArray
                    }, callback);
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
        });
    }
    function callback(results, status) {

    if (status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        setMapOnAllImmo(null, count);
        count = count + 1;
    }

    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
        count += 1;
    }
}
```